# how to get every n rows in pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in below format

```
Time       Current
1535628998 0.336701
1535628998 0.318786
1535628998 0.327593
1535628998 0.347806
1535628998 0.345533

...... around 600 rows in between 

1535628999 0.286297
1535628999 0.359201
1535628999 0.328524
1535628999 0.264149
.................. 
1535629000 0.292071
1535629000 0.394397
1535629000 0.321624
1535629000 0.309555
1535629000 0

.368269
........
```

I want to get every 100 rows in each "Time" by skipping rest of the rows which is in the same "Time".

Any solutions?

Comment: `df.groupby('Time').first()`? `df.groupby('Time').head(n)`?

Comment: You mean 1 row in every 100 rows? i.e. if you had 600 rows, you would get 6 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you needd.

```
df.groupby('Time').head(100)
```

MVCE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Time':[1]*10+[2]*10,'data':np.arange(20)})
df.groupby('Time').head(5)
```

Output:

```
    Time  data
0      1     0
1      1     1
2      1     2
3      1     3
4      1     4
10     2    10
11     2    11
12     2    12
13     2    13
14     2    14
```